# ListBox SelectionChanged Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox Like this

```
 <ListBox Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="7"
             Grid.RowSpan="2"
             Style="{DynamicResource ProductListBoxStyle}"
             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ProductItemTemplate}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding RelatedProducts}"
             ItemsPanel="{DynamicResource ProductListItemsPanelTemplate}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct,Mode=TwoWay}"
             Padding="-12,0,0,0"
             IsHitTestVisible="True"
             ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ProductListItemContainerStyle}"
             x:Name=MyListBox >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCommand}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
```

when I click the same Item again `SelectionChanged` event not firing.

So I added a Button Inside my DataTemplate Like this

```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="ProductItemTemplate">
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand,ElementName=MyListBox}">
            <StackPanel Width="240">
                <Grid Width="Auto"
                      Height="Auto"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Background="White">
                    <Image Source="/Assets/ProductCardBg.png"
                           Width="Auto"
                           Height="Auto" />
                    <Image Source="{Binding ThumbImage}"
                           Width="207"
                           Height="216" />
                </Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                           Margin="0,5,0,0"
                           Style="{StaticResource SWMRegularTextBlockStyle}"
                           FontSize="{StaticResource VerySmallFontSize}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"
                           Style="{StaticResource SWMLightTextBlockStyle}"
                           FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Price}"
                           Style="{StaticResource SWMRegularTextBlockStyle}"
                           FontSize="{StaticResource SmallFontSize}" />

            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But My problem is whenever I select the Item The command is not executed. I need to click Outside of the StackPanel then only the command getting executed. But I need to execute the command whenever I click the Item.

Please someone help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SelectionChanged` means the selection *changed*. Opening/closing the ListBox without changing the selection won't fire it.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish with the button either...

Comment: @canton7 SelectionChanged Event is not firing when I select the same Item again,To get rid of this thing I added a Button Inside the Itemtemplate But button command is not executed when click I the Item, but if I click the corners of the item means Its Executing the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In My ViewModel

```
 private void ReatedItemSelected()
    {
        //After My code
        SelectedProduct = null;
    }
```

after my code if I simply set `SelectedProduct` as null,the `selectionchanged` Event Firing again and I don't need Button in My dataTemplate. `SelectedProduct` is Bound to UI and Set mode as Twoway.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can achieve it by using MouseClick event:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyListBox ,Path=SelectedItem}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

and in the code behind:

```
void MyListBox_MyListBox(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
 //Your code
}
```

If you want to use command and not the code behind do something like that:

create a class called BaseCommand:

```
    public class BaseCommand : ICommand
        {
            protected Func<object, bool> _canExecute;
            protected Action<object> _execute;

            public BaseCommand()
            {
            }

            public BaseCommand(Func<object, bool> canExcecute, Action<object> execute)
            {
                _canExecute = canExcecute;
                _execute = execute;
            }
            public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
            {
                return _canExecute(parameter);


 }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }

 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
 {
     return _canExecute(parameter);
 }

public void Execute(object parameter)
 {
      _execute(parameter);
 }
```

in you ViewModel:

```
private BaseCommand _mouseClick;
public BaseCommand MouseClick
{
   get
   {
     if (null == _mouseClick)
                {
                   _mouseClick = new BaseCommand(CanExecuteCommand, OpenDocument);
                }
                return _open;
   }
}

 private bool CanExecuteCommand(object obj)
        {
            return true; //for example
        }

 public void MouseClickCommand(object o)
{
//do something
}
```

This way every time you'll select an item it'll activate the command.

Comment: Thankyou.. Its worked. But I found Simple solution If I set the SelectedItem as null means Its working perfectly and I don't need Button in my datatemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectionChangedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}">
```

if you change your style button will stretch where ever you inside listItem then button event will fire. Remove the interaction command.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call the command in the `set` part of your Property?

```
private object _SelectedProduct;

public object SelectedProduct
{
    get { return _SelectedProduct; }
    set
    {
        _SelectedProduct = value;

        //Call a method in your view model here.
        DoSomethingUseful();
    }
}
```

Comment: The setter doesn't call when you re-select the same Item in Listbox.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use **MouseUp/Down Event** if you want to get something to execute each time the item is selected (or even a same item is selected again) !!